# Asymptotic AdS and coordinate change

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, anti-de-sitter-spacetime

I'm confused that boundary condition in 2d AdS spacetime. In two dimensions, we can write the metric in conformal gauge,
\begin{align}
ds^2=e^{2\omega(u,v)} dudv.
\end{align}
Suppose we impose the equation of motion $R=-2$, then the metric has the concrete form
\begin{align}
ds^2=-\frac{4\partial_u U(u) \partial_v V(v)}{(U(u)-V(v))^2}dudv.
\end{align}
where $U(u)$ and $V(v)$ is any chiral function. However, if we want holographic description, this metric has to become asymptotic AdS near the boundary (Poincare patch)
\begin{align}
ds^2=\frac{-dt^2 + dz^2}{z^2}
\end{align}
Here's a question. Don't all $U(u)$ and $V(v)$ satisfy this? In https://arxiv.org/abs/2210.10846 , they say that this condition restricts us to $$U(u=t+z)=V(v=t-z)$$ near the boundary $(z \to 0)$ on page 20. Mathematically this makes sense. It is true that when $U(u)=u^2, V(v)=v$ and $u=t+z, v=t-z$, in fact $ds^2 \sim (-dt^2+dz^2)/z^2$ does not hold near the boundary. but this is a **just diffeomorphism**, so the physical properties are the same, just the coordinate is different. On the other hand, I think the boundary of AdS is a physical property of spacetime. Therefore, I think this is just looking the different patch in global AdS. Can we really break this physical property by taking peculiar coordinate? Or is it important to look at it in terms of fixed coordinates, such as $t, z$? More specifically, are there coordinate transformations in flat space that break asymptotic flat? Many thanks.